# How do I modify Login page submit to call my custom function before the normal flow in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, authentication, form-submit

I want to modify the login page of Sharepoint 2010 to change the normal flow during page submit. I want my custom function to be called, Validate it and go to actual submition of the page based on the validation result.

I have tried calling my custom function using *onclientclick* in the "asp: Button" tag. The custom function gets invoked, but I am unable to make the flow complete by sumbitting the login page. Once the custom function gets executed, the whole execution is stopped.

Please help me in solving it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my self. As mentioned I had added an extra submit button. SO when a user clicks the 'Sign In' button the custom function is called. On its success I made the original asp:button to click.